# Extract text from PDF File using Python with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, scripting, scrapy, pypdf

I want to extract text from a given PDF.

The code used is:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
def extract_information(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        number_of_pages = pdf.getNumPages()
        for pages in range(number_of_pages):
            page=pdf.getPage(pages)
            page_content=page.extractText()
            print(page_content)
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'test.pdf'
    extract_information(path)
```

but when I run the above code I get the following output:

```
PS E:\Omkar\Coding\Python\pdfSearch> python .\scrape.py
 !"#$%&!'()*+&,$ !")-!+)-. !"#$%$&'$%%()%*)(+(+$,-,.-+/ 0 1234#5$&3-6#3#1!4#5$78-$0#5"#3$9:;;#<$=-$%(+,(>(?/0&1(+$2(3)-4!+&)(@15#123"$ A8B-C9D;E:F0G$;@HFI%*,JJ>*%J/H F=-D2K#3B#=->.J*EKK4=- 1#L#342L#$M!152!K$M!1#$M&1NO?JP%%$D9QQ9;IR$SDTC$*E
;FM:0@HC$:FDDG$HU$%%/%?
V>%?W*%JPJ?++ A&3#=%(+,(>(?X:ED@@G$0FM:E9D%(+,(>(?X:ED@@G$0FM:E9D%(+,(>(?X:ED@@G$0FM:E9D%(+,(>(?X:ED@@G$0FM:E9D%(+,(>(?X:ED@@G$0FM:E9D%(+,(>(?X:ED@@G$0FM:E9DQ!Y=V?,,W>J/P/*,/H!Z#-X:ED@@G$0FM:E9DR#Y-$0C@S-$+*)%+)%..* A&3#-$*/>,,J(?*>F3$M!1#$@'-X:ED@@G$0FM:E9D$
E551#BB-(*?$M9CE;:[;RI$ET9$%S
 !42#34$FC-$,.>>J>?C2!"$M&5#B-M&N8$;#N&14\(+O?(?\>%O.
C!4#$M&]]#K4#5-I2Z#$M&]]#K4#5-
Q!B423"-$^_I2Z#5$[123#$M&]]#K42&3-$^$$$_
H&3$'!B423"-$^`$_T&]aZ#-
M!]]$;#Ba]4B-$^$$$_M&ZZ#34B- !42#34-F3Ba1!3K#-M]2#34-0#52K!25-0#52K!1#-;!2]1&!5$0M;-
F3Ba1#5$H!Z#-F3Ba1!3K#$ ]!3-9ZN]&8#1)61&aN$H!Z#- &]2K8=-61&aN) ]!3=-%()%+)(+%%-+>$!Z
`X:ED@@G$0FM:E9D$
;#]!42&3BA2N-R#]'bXJJ>(,H$$$5!+&1(+$2(3)-4!+&)(2(*6-!(,1$2(3)-4!+&)(%&!'()*&*$/)71*891,&41($2(3)-4!+&)(;VRRIW6US6;UDSMVS]&&5$Ma]4W
:-71-17$;1*+*
M9CE;:[;RI$HU$%%,%J
09I;@ D[R$0MC$^/>>%(_$ O@O$S@`$%.JJ$H9c$U@;X$HU$
%+%%J%.JJ
OM@TFC%.$RE;RPM@T($$`$$(+(/ A8O$H!Z#-C9D;E:F0G$;@HFI A8B2K2!3$$R2"3!4a1#-
```

I think this has to be something related to the encoding used in the PDF but I am not able to understand this.

[link to the pdf used](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18-wq-KgBgx_umcsROSYQTDANLRGbH6aa/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract Text from PDF you need use OCR, in my opinion best OCR its Tesseract OCR, developed by Google, you can just install pytesseract and use it like you use on your pdf, but i highly recommend use with openCV for use OCR just on text

https://towardsdatascience.com/extracting-text-from-scanned-pdf-using-pytesseract-open-cv-cd670ee38052

Answer (score 1):

I using pdfminer to extract pdf. You can refer example code.

```
#pip install pdfminer.six
import io

from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    '''Convert pdf content from a file path to text

    :path the file path
    '''
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()

    with io.StringIO() as retstr:
        with TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec,
                           laparams=laparams) as device:
            with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
                interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
                password = ""
                maxpages = 0
                caching = True
                pagenos = set()

                for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp,
                                              pagenos,
                                              maxpages=maxpages,
                                              password=password,
                                              caching=caching,
                                              check_extractable=True):
                    interpreter.process_page(page)

                return retstr.getvalue()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(convert_pdf_to_txt('test.pdf'))
```

For more information about this lid. You can refer link below

[PDFminer](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)